# CreateNewBlock : ConnectBlock Fail

Tags: bitcoind, alternatives, altcoin, compiling, quarkcoin

Error Message at server 2 / 3 (peers trying to connect to main server)

root@ubuntu:~/dogequark/src# cat ~/.dogequark/dogequark.cterminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
      what():  CreateNewBlock() : ConnectBlock failed

This is what happen when I try run my daemon at another server, I try run at another few server same issue.

This is my main server node debug.log

```
1 addresses found from DNS seeds
dnsseed thread exit
addcon thread start
msghand thread start
dumpaddr thread start
init message: Done loading
GetMyExternalIP() received [198.204.236.50] 198.204.236.50:0
GetMyExternalIP() returned 198.204.236.50
AddLocal(198.204.236.50:8008,4)
accepted connection 198.204.228.10:57360
send version message: version 70001, blocks=0, us=198.204.236.50:8008, them=198.204.228.10:57360, peer=198.204.228.10:57360
Added time data, samples 2, offset -11 (+0 minutes)
Added 198.204.228.10:8008 from 198.204.228.10: 0 tried, 2 new
Moving 198.204.228.10:8008 to tried
receive version message: version 70001, blocks=0, us=198.204.236.50:8008, them=198.204.228.10:8008, peer=198.204.228.10:57360
getblocks -1 to 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 limit 500
socket closed
disconnecting node 198.204.228.10:57360
trying connection 198.204.228.10:8008 lastseen=0.0hrs
connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 198.204.228.10:8008 lastseen=0.0hrs
connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 198.204.228.10:8008 lastseen=0.0hrs
connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 198.204.228.10:8008 lastseen=0.0hrs
connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
```

My conf file for main server

```
rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=password
rpcallowip=*
port=8008
rpcport=9008
listen=1
server=1
daemon=1
gen=0
```

My conf file for alternate server

```
rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=password
rpcallowip=*
port=8008
rpcport=9008
listen=1
server=1
daemon=1
gen=1
addnode=198.204.236.50
```

Hope to get some help, I trying to learn how to launch my own coin and practice my cpp coding.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I trying to ask how to resolve the connect block issue or what actually causes it. Thanks :)

Comment: What's the last few log entries prior to the one you posted? Have you tried adding more debug output to the `ConnectBlock` function?